# Android: swipe action in fragment to open bottom sheet dialog

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

i have a layout like this

[image]

i want then i swipe up fragment, my bottom sheet will open. How can i do that?

**I really appreciate your help and hope you have a nice day!**

Comment: https://github.com/Deepanshibajaj1503/BottomSheetFragment

Answer (score 0):

As your template shows, the fragment you want to open by swipe is already shown on the screen. In this case you better read about [Material Bottom Sheet](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/package-summary)
The way you can do this swipe action depends on layout below the bottomsheet. For example, scrollable views like NestedScrollView or RecyclerView have [OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener) where you can easily control state and position(transition) of bottomsheet.
On the other hand, if your foreground layout is not scrollable, try adding CoordinatorLayout for some magic =)

Comment: thanks so much , i'm learning.

Comment: welcome! read more official articles and docs